# NSInvalidArgumentException using SFML on macOS

Tags: objective-c, sfml, objective-c++, core-foundation

I am trying to build the Pong example that is distributed with SFML. I am using the latest macOS.

The code compiles, however when I launch I get the following error:

```
pong[14920:316603] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
  '-[SFOpenGLView updateCursorGrabbed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa02948e890'
...
```

I am not familiar with Objective-C/C++, so I have the following questions:

- What does this error mean?
- How do I know what the valid NS arguments are?
- Why is SFML trying to use invalid arguments; do I need to update?

Comment: The important fact is `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. It means you are calling a method that is unknown on that object: `-[SFOpenGLView updateCursorGrabbed]` => `-` means it's an object method, `SFOpenGLView` the class of the object where you did the call and `updateCursorGrabbed` the method you called. But according to https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Window/OSX/SFOpenGLView.mm, it exists `SFOpenGLView` objects have a method `updateCursorGrabbed`.

Comment: @Larme What do you mean by "unknown on that object"? Shouldn't the type-checker catch this?

Comment: If you "write it yourself" yes, but you can always cast to lure the compiler, and often, it's due to the fact that when you retrieved the object, it was "id" on the returned method (like `objectAtIndex:`, `objectForKey:`...), and you thought the returned value was from that class, but in fact no. Or you didn't set the custom class on the Storyboard, etc.